# Cancel a running query

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have an application where users are running a geospatial query against a mongo database. The query can return many thousands of results (~50k). These results are then streamed to the client over a websocket. However, users can abort a request mid result set and execute a new query. Users will frequently start, abort, and re-start requests on the order of several times per minute. Sometimes they even cancel/restart every couple of seconds.

The question is, when a user aborts a request, how do I cancel the query on the server so it doesn't continue to tie up resources streaming back thousands of unneeded results? I'm currently calling `destroy()` on the cursor, but it's not clear that this is actually stopping the query from executing on the server.

What's the best practice in this case?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?

1. db.currentOp()
2. db.killOp(IDRETURNEDHE)

This is a good [example](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/60029/how-do-i-safely-kill-long-running-operations-in-mongodb/60030#60030).

Answer (score 0):

The answer is it depends upon a lot of your implementation details.

If your server is in the middle of streaming results (e.g. still hasn't sent or queued everything) when the server receives some sort of other message that the previous results should be cancelled, then it is possible for you to communicate with that other stream and tell it to stop sending.  How exactly you would do that depends entirely upon your code and you would have to show us your code for us to know.

Chances are the db query is long since complete and what is going on is the server is in the process of streaming results to the client.  So, if that's the case, then it isn't the db you're looking for, it's the code that streams the response to the client.  Since node.js JS is single threaded, the only time another request would actually get run on the server would be while the streaming code was in some async write operation, waiting for that to finish.  You would probably have to set some flag that was uniquely associated with a particular user and then your stream code would have to check for that flag before each chunk of data was sent.  If it saw the cancel flag, it could abandon sending the rest of the results.

You could make things more cancellable by explicitly chunking your results (say 500 at a time) and checking for a cancel flag between the sending of each chunk.

If, on the other hand, all the data has already been buffered up by the TCP layer on the server, then the only way to stop that from being sent is to tear down the webSocket and force the client to reconnect.

Comment: There is already code in place to cancel sending results to the client over the websocket (something very similar to what you've suggested). My question is really specific to cancelling the query execution (and subsequent streaming of results to the client) at the MongoDB layer.

Comment: @herbrandson - Then show us the particular database code you're talking about and the sequencing code that controls when everything runs.  Questions about code need to include the relevant code.